# Продление аккаунта разработчика apple

Tags: xcode, ios

Здравствуйте. Не подскажете, как продлить аккаунт разработчика apple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

схема простая - заходите на сайт https://developer.apple.com/ -> member center -> certificates -> выбираете нужную лицензию(ios,os x, safari). вводите данные кредитки, получаете на почту письмо с кодом активации. пока не активируете покупку - Ваша лицензия не обновится.

еще такой момент - возможность продлить лицензию появляется где-то за месяц до истечения срока действия текущей.

и не забудьте потом обновить сертификаты разработчика, распространителя.. у них тоже срок ограниченный годом

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я просто думал, что продлить можно в любой момент.

Answer (score 0):

[Продление аккаунта разработчика apple](http://toster.ru/q/37199)